# How do I tell bash to use /usr/local/bin/python3 instead of /usr/bin/python3?

Tags: python, bash, karabiner, taskwarrior

I perl script that runs the following command:

`/bin/bash -c 'TASKRC=/Users/me/.taskrc /usr/local/bin/task add \'the task\''`

The script works fine when the perl script is run from the command line. The command executes some python code in a library, `tasklib`, to insert a task into a TaskWarrior database.

However, when the perl script is executed indirectly by an app, Karabiner Elements, I get errors.

Some debug statements reveal this when the perl script is run standalone:

```
Python version: 3.9.9
Python bin: /usr/local/bin/python3
```

However, when Karabiner executes the perl script, I see:

```
Python version: 3.8.9
Python bin: /usr/bin/python3
```

So an older 3.8 version of `tasklib` is getting used. I need to somehow to tell bash to use the 3.9.9 version of python so it can find the newer `tasklib` library found in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. How do I do this?

Comment: Put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. But looks like that's already the case at least in my interactive terminal. `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`. How might I check that with the system bash, which I assume karabiner is using.

Comment: Where is python being run from?

Comment: An app called Karabiner Elements runs: `/usr/local/bin/bash -c '~/bin/taskwiki_helper.pl watchlist'`. The perl script it executes does: `/usr/local//bin/bash -c 'TASKRC=$ENV{HOME}/.taskrc /usr/local/bin/task`. This in turn calls some python code. The python code is what is choking because it's using an old library.

Comment: They python code that chokes is a custom hook to the `tasklib` library which has the code to modify `TaskWarrior`. That code is here: https://github.com/tbabej/taskpirate/blob/master/on-add-pirate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; TASKRC=/Users/me/.taskrc task add "the task"'
```

Comment: That did it! Awesome. Been researching this for hours.